# Arrange Ggplots in GridExtra with Set of Column Names and Row Names in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have this 15 set of `ggplots` that I want to give a set of `colnames` to as `cnames  <- c('phi = 0.8', 'phi = 0.9', 'phi = 0.95')` and row names as `rnames <- c("NBB", "MBB", "CBB", "MBB1", "CBB1")`.

```
#simple plot
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt,mpg))

# load package
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
# setting-up grid of plots...5 columns by 3 rows 
sample <- grid.arrange(p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       p + geom_line() + theme_bw(),
                       ncol = 3)
```

[image: Grid Arrange From gridExtra]

I want the row names to be rotated at `90 degree` while the column name be at `normal degree`

**EDIT**

I want output similar to this.

[image: grid Arrange]

Comment: I need help please

Comment: Looks like you may need `facet_wrap` `rerun(15, mtcars %>% select(mpg, wt)) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>% ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~ grp)`